# Yearly Archive Page?

Tags: archives

Is it possible to have Wordpress automatically create yearly archive pages; simarily to how it creates monthly archive pages.
For example: blog/2013/07/ shows all the posts form July, 2013 and like to be able to put in blog/2013/ to get all the posts from that year.

Comment: `blog/2013/` should return all the posts from that year. What problems are you facing?

Comment: I think is a result of my Magneto-WP integration